# How to format an entire column in math mode using \mathrm

Tags: tables, math-mode, columns, mathrm

I'm making a table with a column full of equations. To avoid the repetitive usage of `$\mathrm{equation}$` in each row, I used `\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}}` and it works perfectly, however, I'd like to use the command `\mathrm` avoiding the italic format. How can I include the `\mathrm` in the entire column format?

EDIT 1:

A MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c>{$}c<{$}S}
\midrule
\textbf{Solution} & \textbf{Chemicals} & \textbf{Concentration (mg/mL)} \\
\midrule
A & NaNO_{3} & 8,500 \\
& MgSO_{4}\cdot7H_{2}O & 2,450 \\
& MgCl_{2}\cdot6H_{2}O & 2,050 \\
& CaCl_{2}\cdot2H_{2}O & 1,450 \\
\\
B & KH_{2}PO_{4} & 8,700 \\
& Na_{2}HPO_{4} & 7,060 \\
\\
C & H_{3}BO_{3} & 24,800 \\
& MnCl_{2}\cdot4H_{2}O & 13,900 \\
& FeCl_{3}\cdot6H_{2}O & 10,800 \\
& ZnCl_{2} & 3,350 \\
& CoCl_{2}\cdot6H_{2}O & 0,190 \\
& CuCl_{2} & 0,011 \\
\\
D & EDTA\cdot Na_{2} & 18,600 \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a couple of rows of the table, just to play with what you already have?

Comment: don't tell anyone but you can use `>{$\rm}c<{$}` although now you have added an example it looks like one of the chemistry package macros might be more suitable than bare math mode

Comment: @egreg I posted the MWE

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Use a specialized package for chemistry, for instance `mhchem`, that also eases input. Together with `collcell` you get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,},
  per-mode=symbol,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  >{\collectcell\ce}c<{\endcollectcell}
  S[table-format=2.3]
}
\midrule
\textbf{Solution} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Chemicals}} & {\textbf{Concentration}} \\
&& {(\si{\milli\gram\per\milli\liter})} \\
\midrule
A & NaNO3 & 8,500 \\
  & MgSO4 . 7 H_{2}O & 2,450 \\
  & MgCl2 . 6 H_{2}O & 2,050 \\
  & CaCl2 . 2 H_{2}O & 1,450 \\
\addlinespace
B & KH2PO4 & 8,700 \\
  & Na2HPO4 & 7,060 \\
\addlinespace
C & H3BO3 & 24,800 \\
  & MnCl2 . 4 H_{2}O & 13,900 \\
  & FeCl3 . 6 H_{2}O & 10,800 \\
  & ZnCl2 & 3,350 \\
  & CoCl2 . 6 H_{2}O & 0,190 \\
  & CuCl2 & 0,011 \\
\addlinespace
D & EDTA\cdot Na2 & 18,600 \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi egreg how are you? +1 for you excellent work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `collcell` for it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\mymathrm}[1]{$\mathrm{#1}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{>{\collectcell\mymathrm}c<{\endcollectcell}}
    E = mc^2\\
    E = hf
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You can change the definition of `\mymathrm` to anything that accepts one argument, including a chemistry macro.